# Have multiple jquery tabs on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I really need some help with jquery tabs. I have found some answers to the question I'm about to ask, but the issue is that most jquery tabs uses "a" tag for navigation and I spent time to get mine to work without "a" tag. I want to keep it that way for a very good reason.

Here's my question. I have a jquery tab that works very well. But when I try to put more than one tab in the same page, it contradicts each other.

Here's a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2f4w9ru/). I tried to duplicate the jquery code and change the IDs and classes to conform with the second tab, but can't seem to get it to work.

Imagine I have 5 content sections on my homepage and I want section 2 and 5 to have tabs.

Here's the css:

```
#tabs-nav-wrap {padding:10px 0; text-align: center;}
#tabs-nav-wrap ul {display: inline-block; list-style: none;}

#tabs-nav-wrap ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;

  margin:0 3px;
}
#tabs-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background: #736565;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  border:1px solid #615656;
}

#tabs-nav .tab-nav-link.current,
#tabs-nav .tab-nav-link:hover {
  border:1px solid #5eaace;
  background: #74c1e4;
}

.tab-content {padding:20px 0; text-align: center;}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="tabs-nav-wrap">
        <ul id="tabs-nav">
            <li class="tab-nav-link" data-target="#tab-one">TAB 1</li>
            <li class="tab-nav-link" data-target="#tab-two">TAB 2</li>
            <li class="tab-nav-link" data-target="#tab-three">TAB 3</li>        
         </ul>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
     </div><!-- ends tabs-nav-wrap -->    


 <div class="tabs-main-content">

      <div id="tab-one" class="tab-content"><!-- Begins tab-one -->
         <div class="tab-inner">
            <p>Tab 1 content here.</p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tab-two" class="tab-content"><!-- Begins tab-two -->
         <div class="tab-inner">
            <p>Tab 2 content here.</p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tab-three" class="tab-content"><!-- Begins tab-three -->
         <div class="tab-inner">
            <p>Tab 3 content here.</p>
         </div>
      </div>    

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div><!-- # tabs-main-content -->
```

Here's what my jquery code looks like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
  $('#tabs-nav .tab-nav-link').bind('click', function(e) {
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $($this.data("target")); // get the target from data attribute
    $('#tabs-nav .tab-nav-link.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $this.addClass('current');
      $target.fadeIn("fast");
    });
  }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

I really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt Yes the fiddle is working. Please read my question to understand what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to have more than one tab on the same page. For example first tab on content section 2 and (second) another tab on content section 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id`, they are unique selectors and you want to handle multiple tabs with same code. Also use `siblings()` to hide or remove class who are not active element. here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2f4w9ru/1/)